# Creating a pipe that can morph types within without experimental::any

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am trying to create a pipe implementation that would expose an interface to chain multiple manipulations on some given data while maintaining immutability of the said data. The caveat here is that the manipulations (which are, obviously, just pure functions) should be able to morph the type of the data (e. g. a pipe that is created from an OpenCV mat that should pass through an OCR tool, which would result in a string output). That said, I made this implementation which utilizes std::experimental::any.

```
class Pipe {
    any data;

public:
    Pipe (any data) : data(data) {}
    any unpack () {
        return data;
    }

    Pipe operator| (function<any(any)> reducer) {
        return Pipe(reducer(this->unpack()));
    }

    Pipe operator|| (any & destination) {
        destination = unpack();
        return *this;
    }

    static Pipe from (any data) {
        return Pipe(data);
    }
};
```

So the API for this pipe-thingy is as follows:

```
Pipe::from(some_data) | do_something | do_something_else || unpacked
```

Well, it works. The problem is that it is error-prone, since you have to use explicit `any_cast` any time you want to actually access the data concealed by `any`. That said, any reducer function has to guess what type it will receive, and if that doesn't match the reality, that's a runtime error, i.e. a lot of unnecessary try-catches or something in the code, as well as those additional lines for explicit typecasting.

So I have two questions about this 'pipe thingy'.

1. Is it possible to make this less error-prone?
2. Is is possible to achieve the same effect without using `any`? Maybe some template classes, anything would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template can indeed remove the use of `any`, something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Pipe {
    T data;

public:
    Pipe (T data) : data(data) {}
    const T& unpack () const { return data; }
    T& unpack () { return data; }

    template <typename F>
    auto operator| (F reducer) -> decltype(reducer(std::declval<T>()))
    {
        return Pipe<decltype(reducer(data))>(reducer(data));
    }

    Pipe operator|| (T& destination) const
    {
        destination = unpack();
        return *this;
    }

};

template <typename T>
Pipe<T> MakePipe(T data) {
    return Pipe<T>(data);
}
```

The usage would be

```
MakePipe(some_data) | do_something | do_something_else || unpacked;
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, this is a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

So piping is about flow not about storing data.

```
namespace plumbing {
  // tags to identify plumping components:
  struct pipe_tag {};
  struct src_tag{};
  struct sink_tag{};

  // this lets us tag function objects.  To handle function pointers,
  // we need a specialization.
  template<class F, class Tag>
  struct tagged_f:F,Tag{
    using F::F;
    tagged_f(F&& f):F(std::move(f)){}
  };
  template<class Tag, class F>
  tagged_f<F,Tag> tag(F f){ return {std::move(f)}; }
  // detect various tags:
  template<class F> using is_pipe = std::is_base_of<pipe_tag, F>;
  template<class F> using is_src = std::is_base_of<src_tag, F>;
  template<class F> using is_sink = std::is_base_of<sink_tag, F>;

  // type erased versions of the plumbing components
  // useful to store the end result of a plumbing job:
  template<class T>
  using gen_sink = tagged_f<std::function<void(T)>, sink_tag>;
  template<class T>
  using gen_src = tagged_f<std::function<void(gen_sink<T>)>, src_tag>;
  template<class In, class Out>
  using gen_pipe = tagged_f<std::function<void(gen_src<In>, gen_sink<Out>)>, pipe_tag>;

  // SFINAE helper using the is_X templates above:    
  template<class T, template<class...>class Test>
  using check=std::enable_if_t< Test<T>{}, bool >;

  // really simple source, pipe and sink helpers:
  template<class T>
  auto simple_src( T in ){
    return tag<src_tag>([=](auto&& sink){ sink(in); });
  }
  template<class F>
  auto simple_pipe( F f ){
    return tag<pipe_tag>( [=](auto&& src, auto&& sink){
      src([&](auto&& in){sink(f(in));});         
    });
  }
  template<class V>
  auto vector_sink(V& v){
    return tag<sink_tag>([&](auto&&t){ v.push_back(decltype(t)(t)); });
  }

  // operator| implementations:

  // Src|Pipe is a Src:
  template<class Src, class Pipe,
    check<Src, is_src> =true,
    check<Pipe, is_pipe> =true
  >
  auto operator|( Src src, Pipe pipe ){
    return tag<src_tag>([=](auto&& sink){
      pipe( src, sink );
    });
  }

  // Pipe|Sink is a Sink:
  template<class Pipe, class Sink,
    check<Sink, is_sink> =true,
    check<Pipe, is_pipe> =true
  >
  auto operator|( Pipe pipe, Sink sink ){
    return tag<sink_tag>([=](auto&& t){
      pipe( simple_src(t), sink );
    });
  }

  // Pipe|Pipe is a Pipe:
  template<class PipeA, class PipeB,
    check<PipeA, is_pipe> =true,
    check<PipeB, is_pipe> =true
  >
  auto operator|( PipeA a, PipeB b ){
    return tag<pipe_tag>([=](auto&& src, auto&& sink){
      b( src|a, sink );
    });
  }

  // Src|Sink is a callable object on 0 arguments:
  template<class Src, class Sink,
    check<Src, is_src> =true,
    check<Sink, is_sink> =true
  >
  auto operator|( Src src, Sink sink ){
    return [=]{ src(sink); };
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3610b103fdbaed45).

This lets you set up a stateless pipe chain, type erase it (using `gen_pipe<In,Out>`), have 1 chunk of data become zero or many, buffer and work on strings (if you add terminating symbols), etc.

A sink of T is a function that consumes T.

A source of T is a function that consumes sinks of T.  This permits them to produce more than 1.

A pipe from T to U is a function that takes both a source of T and a sink of U.

Data is not stored in the pipes but rather flows through them.

```
using namespace plumbing;
std::vector<int> v;
// build pipe, don't run it:
auto code = simple_src(7)|simple_pipe([](auto x){return x*2;})|vector_sink(v);
// run pipe:
code(); // v contains {14}
// print:
for (auto x:v)
    std::cout << x << "\n";
```

These pipes are untyped, and check that the types match when you connect them.

So you can have a sink like this:

```
auto print_sink = tag<sink_tag>( [](auto&& x){ std::cout << x; } );
```

This same sink can be connected to multiple different types of data.

```
auto hello_world_src = tag<src_tag>( [](auto&& sink) {
  for (char c : "hello world")
    sink(c);
});
```

then

```
(hello_world_src|print_sink)();
```

prints `"hello world"`.  Meanwhile

```
(simple_src(3.14)|print_sink)();
```

prints `3.14`.

We can even get fancy:

```
auto foreach_src = [](auto&& c){
  return tag<src_tag>([c=decltype(c)(c)](auto&& sink) {
    for( auto&& x:c )
      sink(decltype(x)(x));
  });
};
```

This is a function that takes a range and returns a source over the elements of the container.

```
auto foreach_pipe = tag<pipe_tag>([foreach_src]( auto&& src, auto&& sink ) {
  src( [&](auto&& c) {
    foreach_src(c)(sink);
  } );
});
```

This is a pipe.  It takes a source of ranges, and a sink of elements, and connects them.

[With more examples](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2afb965d41fcecde)

Comment: This deserves some appreciation.
Thanks.

Comment: @StargazingTux Typos fixed, live example added.